# Extract word from a line between a specific position and the next delimiter Java

Tags: java, string, join, split

I have a text file which contain many lines, every line contain many words separated by delimiter like "hello,world,I,am,here".

I want to extract some words between position and delimiter for example:
the position is 7 so the string is "world" and if the position was 1 the string will be "hello"

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the `split()` method. With commas delimiting the words you would do this:

```
String[] words = "hello,world,I,am,here".split(",");
```

Then you can get the words by position by indexing into the array:

```
words[3] // would yield "am"
```

Note that the parameter to `split()` is a regular expression, so if you aren't familiar with them [see the docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (or google for a tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the following code while taking advantage of the method `split()` that can be used an all Strings objects :

```
String line = "hello,world,I,am,here";
String[] words = line.split(",");
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12. thats the exception when I want to read words[12]

Comment: You only have 5 words in that String. So the `words` array will only have five elements with a maximum index of `4`

Comment: I understand, but in my code, I'm reading a file line by line and inside the while loop, I want to extract some word from a specific position. 
   while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
     String[] result = strLine.split(",");
     
     System.out.println(result[1]);  }

Comment: If each line may not have 12 words and may have less then use an `if ` statement such as: `if(words.length() >= 12)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String wordAtPosition(String line, int position) {
    String[] words = line.split(",");
    int index = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        index += word.length();
        if (position < index) {
            return word;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Example

```
String line = "hello,world,I,am,here";
String word = wordAtPosition(line, 7);
System.out.println(word); // prints "world"
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the substring , then split and get first element from Array.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Test test = new Test();
        String t = test.getStringFromLocation("hello,world,I,am,here", 1, ",");
        System.out.println(t);
        t = test.getStringFromLocation("hello,world,I,am,here", 7, ",");
        System.out.println(t);

        t = test.getStringFromLocation("hello,world,I,am,here", 6, ",");
        System.out.println(t);

    }

    public String getStringFromLocation(final String input, int position,
            String demlimter) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        int absoulutionPosition = position - 1;
        String[] value = input.substring(absoulutionPosition).split(demlimter);
        return value.length > 0 ? value[0] : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most readable solution but covers corner cases. The split solutions are nice but does not reflect the position in the original string since it skips the ',' from the count

```
String line = "hello,world,I,am,here";
int position = new Random().nextInt(line.length());
int startOfWord = -1;
int currentComa = line.indexOf(",", 0);
while (currentComa >= 0 && currentComa < position) {
    startOfWord = currentComa;
    currentComa = line.indexOf(",", currentComa + 1);
}
int endOfWord = line.indexOf(",", position);
if(endOfWord < 0) {
    endOfWord = line.length();
}
String word = line.substring(startOfWord + 1, endOfWord);
System.out.println("position " + position + ", word " + word);
```